# Invalid cast from type 'MyStruct' to type 'void*'

Tags: python, c++, function, struct, functor

I have a struct called `Spiketimesolver` defined in the following header file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "plot_support.h"

struct Spiketimesolver {
  const Doub tau_0, I_0, V_start, I_start;
Spiketimesolver(const Doub tau_0, const Doub I_0, const Doub V_start,
                const Doub I_start) :
  tau_0(tau_0), I_0(I_0), V_start(V_start), I_start(I_start)
  {}
  Doub operator()(const Doub t) {
    const Doub I = get_I(I_start, t, tau_0);
    const Doub V = get_V(I_start, t, tau_0, I_0, V_start, I);
    return 0.5 * pow((V - 1), 2);
  }
};
```

(`get_I` and `get_V` are defined in my file `plot_support.h`.  Their definitions are irrelevant here.)

In a separate module, I instantiate this struct as follows:

```
Spiketimesolver solver(tau_0, I_0, V_start, I_start);
```

Here, all the arguments are doubles.

I want to pass `solver` to a function I have defined thus:

```
template<class T> PyObject* NRpyObject(T &a) {
// default applies to all function objects or other structs
    PyObject *thing = PyCapsule_New((void*)a,NULL,NULL);
    return thing;
}
```

[`PyCapsule_New`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/capsule.html#c.PyCapsule_New) is part of the Python C API.  It expects `void *pointer` as the first argument.

When I try to compile, I get the following error for the call `NRpyObject(solver)`:

```
In file included from analysis_cmodule.cpp:2:0:
nr3python.h: In instantiation of ‘PyObject* NRpyObject(T&) [with T = Spiketimesolver; PyObject = _object]’:
analysis_cmodule.cpp:16:27:   required from here
nr3python.h:183:52: error: invalid cast from type ‘Spiketimesolver’ to type ‘void*’
  PyObject *thing = PyCapsule_New((void*)a,NULL,NULL);
                                                    ^
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to [`PyCapsule_New`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/capsule.html) needs to be a pointer. You are trying to accomplish that by casting `a` to `void*`. However, the compiler does not like that. I am guessing that you need to use:

```
PyObject *thing = PyCapsule_New(&a,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: many thanks!  is there any way for me to achieve this without editing the code in `NRpyObject`?  can i pass something other than `solver` to `NRpyObject` -- like `&solver`, etc.?

Comment: i say this because i didn't write `NRpyObject`, and i don't want to break it.

Comment: passing `&solver` makes the compiler happy . . . but i don't know whether i'm going to get the results i expect . . . we shall see.

Comment: The function `NRpyObject` can be improved, for sure. Good luck.

Comment: hmm, neither my solution nor yours seems to be working.  but i need to do some more fine-grained debugging.

Comment: @dbliss, I would try to allocate an object using heap memory and use that pointer instead of using the address of an object from stack memory.

Comment: i'm not sure what that means.  i think what i may have to do is delete this question and ask a more targeted one about how to send a functor to Python and then pass it, in Python, as an argument to a C++ function.